# How to prevent file creation with psql copy when zero rows are returned from the query without checking the count of query result?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm using the postgres copy to create a csv file with header as below.

```
\copy (select * from result_table) To '/ldb_db/shared/data/cctl_reports/output/CCTL_cfs_in_missing.csv' With CSV HEADER ;
```

The `result_table` is a temporary table that I inflate with data from a function that executes before the `\copy`.

Problem is that it's creating an empty file with headers when no records are found. I don't want that happening. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Does table result_table is empty?

Comment: If the table is empty, you don't want generate the result file with just csv header, am I right?

Comment: @Shawn.X Yes. Indeed. And I'd prefer to do it with some options from psql itself.